# LDAP Searching on C# returning more than one entry

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I'm using [.NET Standard LDAP client](https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard) Library to query my AD, since CoreCLR doesn't support DirectoryServices.

I had done the connection with a valid user an password and  used a LdapSearchResults object with an email filter to query the AD.

This query should had returned one result only, as I'm using my AD user email to test, but when I loop through results I got 4 entries.

The first entry corresponds to my user but other entries seem to be empty, throwing an exception when they're reached by the loop.

```
using (var cn = new LdapConnection())
{

cn.Connect("<<myHostname>>", 389);
cn.Bind("<<myUserName>>", "<<myPassword>>");

//with the mail filter I was expecting to retrieve only one entry, but I got 4 instead
LdapSearchResults searchResults = cn.Search("<<mysearchBase>>", LdapConnection.SCOPE_SUB, "(&(objectClass=user)(mail=<<myEmail>>))", null, false);                                  

//This loop is executed 4 times 
//The entry is correct on the first time 
//From the second time all entries are empty and an exception is thrown
while (searchResults.hasMore())
    {
        LdapEntry nextEntry = null;
        try
        {

            nextEntry = searchResults.next();
        }
        catch (LdapException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.LdapErrorMessage);                                
            continue;
        }

        //Here I extract some information from the entry, like group
        Console.WriteLine(nextEntry.getAttribute("memberOf"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you checked the same under `ADUC (dsa.msc)`? There may be chances that the same email-ID is mentioned in 4 user accounts.

Comment: Which line is throwing the Exception?